# Poetry not installing via official method successfully - ModuleNotFound: No module named 'poetry.core.toml'

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm on MacOS, with a 2020 MBP. When I tried updating `poetry` (which I think was on 1.3, to 1.7.1, the current version as of writing) via `poetry self update`, I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poetry.core.toml'
```

I deleted every trace of `poetry` I could find - `rm -rf`ing from my Python's site-packages, using the official uninstall script, nothing in my .zshrc file, removed `~/.local/bin/poetry`, tried different versions, I get the exact same error every single time when I do the simple `poetry --version`.

I have no idea what could be going on, I installed via the official installer and there was no pip nonsense because I wanted to avoid issues like this.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install correctly when I eventually found another install at `/usr/local/bin/poetry` and `rm -rf`d that one too. I'm not sure if this indicates that I installed via a different method (though why would I, the docs make the correct method the easiest one to follow).